# Getting "NOSuchMethodException" in Java Reflection while executing with Excel

Tags: java, reflection, apache-poi

I tried to execute the Selenium code using Java Reflection with Microsoft Excel to achieve Keyword Driven Framework. but code is executing with out any issue but getting "NoSuchMethodException" at the end of the result. can anyone please help in this. I'm new to this "Java Reflection" and "keywordDriven Framework"

```
 for(int Tests=1;Tests<TestData.sheet.getLastRowNum()+1;Tests++){

      if(this.getClass().getSimpleName().contains(TestData.sheet.getRow(Tests).getCell(0).getStringCellValue()))
        { 
                String MethodName=TestData.sheet.getRow(Tests).getCell(2).getStringCellValue();
            try{    
                Method method=FunctionLibrary.class.getMethod(MethodName,String.class,String.class,String.class);
                method.invoke(lib,TestData.sheet.getRow(Tests).getCell(5).getStringCellValue(),TestData.sheet.getRow(Tests).getCell(6).getStringCellValue(),TestData.sheet.getRow(Tests).getCell(4).getStringCellValue());
            }catch(InvocationTargetException | NoSuchMethodException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
          }
        }
```

//Error Log cat//

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: lib.FunctionLibrary.(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
    at testCaseWithKeywordFramework.TestCase1_Login.Login(TestCase1_Login.java:36)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:108)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:669)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:877)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1201)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:776)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:634)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:425)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:420)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:385)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:334)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1318)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1243)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1161)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1129)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:114)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: lib.FunctionLibrary.(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
    at testCaseWithKeywordFramework.TestCase1_Login.Login(TestCase1_Login.java:36)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:108)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:669)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:877)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1201)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:776)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:634)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:425)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:420)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:385)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:334)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1318)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1243)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1161)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1129)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:114)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
```

I dont know why it is continuing the execution even that Classname not matching there.

[ExcelSheetImage Please Check here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cTWws.png)

Comment: Seems like `MethodName` is an empty String

Comment: Hi Deters, it is executing all the methods that i added in excel sheet.. what i'm thinking is it is still exectuing the empty rows also...

Comment: Oh i see, could it be that the Cell contains some Whitespaces at the end? If so, try adding `trim()` to `getStringCellValue` in your comparison.

Comment: Okk Sure.. i will try and let you know :)

Comment: it is not worked.. i added trim but it is not working

Comment: Your code looks fine, can you try looking at the comparison in a Debugger? Or you could add a System.out before the comparison to log boths Strings. There is something weird there

Comment: i'm also answerless for this... why this happening with out classnames matching in If statement

Comment: Hi Deters, i tried with changed to Equals instead of Contains in If statement.. now it works fine.. but one thing i observed is becoz of using Contains it consider the white space also...

Comment: I have one more doubt also.. if you able to help please help me...

Comment: i have different methods with different parameters.... so if have to pass the 4 parameters again i have to change code..instead of that how can i pass the arguments count and argument type into getMethod() with Excel... if you can please sort out this

Comment: `getMethod(name, parameters)` accepts an Array of Classes as parameter types. You would need an Array of Classes and an Array of the Values (Objects) for `method.invoke(lib, values)`. Storing the type in Excel could be done as plain String like `java.lang.String` and then converted with `Class.forName()`. However you would need to convert the String (value) read from the table to the actual parameter type.

Comment: If you dont mine can you please send that code to me.. i.m really saying that i didnt have that much idea on all these things.. it will be a big help if you send that code..